# pd.drop() throws TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, typeerror

The error from the title crops up in a very strange case for me.

I have a dataframe `copy_data` and I am trying to remove a set of columns from it.

I generate the set of column names to remove:

```
set_to_remove = set(list(copy_data)) - set([self.farmConfig['mapping'][column]['column'].split('.')[0] for column in self.farmConfig['mapping']])
```

where `self.farmConfig` has a structure like this:

```
farmConfig = {
    'mapping': {
        'A': {
            'column': 'a'
        },
        'B': {
            'column': 'b'
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

and I can confirm that the result of `set_to_remove` is a valid subset of the set of columns. Then I call `copy_data.drop(list(set_to_remove), inplace=True)`, where I run into this error.

Note that for some reason, this works when copy_data is smaller, but fails when I run it on the full size.

So my questions are - why am I getting this error, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aren't you forgetting the `axis=1` parameter?

```
copy_data.drop(list(set_to_remove), axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: You're right, I am. But how come this error did not crop up with a smaller dataframe?

Comment: No idea, if you share the data we can check

Comment: Ah unfortunately I won't be able to share the data. But do you have any hypotheses?